# Javascript:How to get content of a url?

Tags: javascript

```
As we know, we can use the function `file_get_contents(url)` in PHP to get content of a url.
```

However, can it be avaible in JavaScript?

```
The `document.ElementById()` is only valid in current page.
```

Can I use JS to get a `div` or `class` in an URL?

Moreover, if these content can be displayed through `PopupBubble`, I will be more grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an HTTP request using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) which can be bypassed using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: Or in other words - there's much to learn about JavaScript. The keyword missing in this answer is AJAX

Comment: Thank you. I got an API in chrome extension. It can help me to cross domain access.